# Рандом с одинаковыми соотношениями

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Есть вот такой код.

```
(int Chance, ThingType prize)[] chances =
    {

            (Chance: 50, prize: ThingType.Keg),
            (Chance: 50, prize: ThingType.Health),
    };

    int chance = Random.Range(0, 100) + 1;

    for (int index = 0; index < chances.Length; index++)
    {
        var pair = chances[index];
        if (chance <= pair.Chance)
            return pair.prize;
    }
    return ThingType.Chest;
```

Он позволяет выбрать случайный приз исходя из того, что все вероятности совокупно образуют 100.

Но, если в этом массиве кортежей есть вещи с одинаковым шансом, то получается что будет железно выпадать первая по списку  - в данном случае это `ThingType.Keg` и никогда - вторая по списку, т.е. `ThingType.Keg`

Как написать чтобы он мог успешно обрабатывать массивы кортежей с равными и неравными вероятностями?  Ну т.е. ожидается что то примерно такое

на вход

```
(int Chance, ThingType prize)[] chances =
    {
            (Chance: 70, prize: ThingType.Gold)
            (Chance: 30, prize: ThingType.Kind),
            (Chance: 50, prize: ThingType.Keg),
            (Chance: 50, prize: ThingType.Health),
    };
```

На выходе - 
с 35% шансом вернет `ThingType.Gold`
с 15% шансом вернет `ThingType.Kind`
с 25% шансом вернет `ThingType.Keg`
с 25% шансом вернет `ThingType.Health`

Но что то одно должно вернуть точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Он позволяет выбрать случайный приз исходя из того, что все
>   вероятности совокупно образуют 100.

Нет, он этого не делает.

---

```
double total = sum of all Chance values;

int chance = Random.Range(0, 100) + 1;

int current = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < chances.Length; index++)
{
    var pair = chances[index];
    current = current + pair.Chance / total * 100;
    if (chance <= current)
        return pair.prize;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не ясно откуда взялась переменная `chance`, она используется но не создана до этого

Comment: @Potion Это Ваша переменная.

Comment: Да, вижу, у меня она равна случайному числу от 0 до 100, таким же образом его и использовать?

Comment: @Potion Использовать так, как я показал.